# Don't get a newline (\n)

Tags: php

```
echo 'kar\nthic';
```

My question: is why I am not getting new line. Where I am doing mistake. I tried in google, but I am not getting proper answer. The output should look like below.

```
kar
thic
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to use double quotes to get a new line, since escape sequences are **only** interpreted within double quotes:

```
echo "kar\nthic";
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes
>   (the character ').
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

And then:

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret
>   more escape sequences for special characters.

Note that newline characters `"\n"` are **ignored** by browsers when displaying content, and you will need to use `<br />` to place newlines within HTML output, or use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function:

```
echo nl2br( "kar\nthic");
```

Comment: When I tried to add double quotes i am not getting the output what i required i am getting space

Comment: Look at the source code of your html and you will see the new line character.  If you want a html line break then replace \n with <br />.

Comment: Or wrap the content in `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
echo "kar<br>\nthic";
```

A line break doesn't show up in HTML.

(Editted to include double quotes - good point, nickb)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "kar\nthic";
//or
echo 'kar<br>thic';
//or
echo '<pre>';
echo 'kar\nthic';
echo '</pre>';
// best way
echo nl2br( "kar\nthic");
```

Comment: hi @Miguel

the last one is good but what is the meaning of nl2br

Comment: nl2br Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string --> http://php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 1):

Just for some additional information, the `\n` character will create a new line if you are outputting to a text file, as in:

```
file_put_contents( "out_file.txt", "kar\nthic");
```